# Href to Onclick redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bronto

I have research this topic through the community, although I cannot find an answer. I am using Bronto's direct add feature (attempting to use it), The documentation isn't that great.

In summary, the href link subscribes the user on the email list. The only problem is that this link opens a new page. When I want the user to stay on the same page. I though about doing a redirect, when clicking the link, though I am not sure if that would work.

I have tried this:

```
 //Html
<a id="subscription" href="http://example.com">Subscribe</a>

 // Jquery
  $("#emailsubscribe").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();//this will prevent the link trying to navigate to another page

          //do the update
          var href = "http://example.com";

          //when update has finished, navigate to the other page
          window.location = "href";
   });
```

The goal is that I am trying to make it where the user clicks on the link, it subscribes them to the email list, but immediately redirects them back, without opening another window.

Comment: Instead of redirecting the user or even using an href, just send an AJAX request when the user clicks the link. That will suffice.

Comment: This make sense. After seeing the Answers below. I wanted to know why Ajax? I never used it. (until today)

Comment: Yeah, it is useful for sending HTTP requests without reloading a page or moving to a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for AJAX. This allows you to make requests without actually navigating to a page. Since you're using jQuery

```
$("#emailSubscribe").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get("http://www.myurl.com", function (data) {
      //All done!
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options:

1. Do an AJAX request to subscribe the user

`$('#emailsubscribe').on('click', function () {
        $.get('/email-subscribe/' + USER_ID, function () {
           // redirect goes here
           window.location = 'REDIRECT_URL';
        });
    });`

2. Use an iframe and when the iframe has loaded close the iframe (ugly, hacky, not recommended)
3. Have the subscribe page redirect the user back. Aka do the common messages of "You have been subscribed. Redirecting back in 5seconds...". You would need to pass the redirect link to the subscribe page, aka

   window.location = '/subscribe/USER_ID?redirect_to=/my-redirect-page'

Comment: What makes Ajax do this?

Comment: what you want is to basically load 2 pages. the first page is the "subscribe" page and the second page is the redirect, post-subscribe page. AJAX just loads the subscribe page asynchronously (so it won't be visible to the user)  and when the subscription is successful it redirects. If you want to show both pages you'd want to go with option #3

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer the var, instead of typing another string to redirect.

```
//Html
<a id="subscription" href="http://example.com">Subscribe</a>

// Jquery
$("#emailsubscribe").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();//this will prevent the link trying to navigate to another page

          //do the update
          var href = "http://example.com";

          //when update has finished, navigate to the other page
          window.location = href; //<<<< change this.
});
```